# How to add a simple invoke statement to a class file using asm

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, jvm-bytecode

Consider I have this java program.

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String []args){
        String a = "Dad";      
        System.out.println(a);
}
```

Now I have a ASM code to traverse through the method nodes and can access the instruction in the method. Say I added the invoke method and a ldc for adding a simple print statement.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
    for(Object methodNodeObj : classNode.methods) { 
        MethodNode methodNode = (MethodNode)methodNodeObj;  
        for(AbstractInsnNode abstractInsnNode : methodNode.instructions.toArray()) { 
        }
        InsnList il = new InsnList();
        il.add(new FieldInsnNode(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;"));
        il.add(new LdcInsnNode("Works!"));
        il.add(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "encode", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V"));
         methodNode.instructions.insertBefore(abstractNode, il);
```

This helps in printing a statement...
Suppose if I have a ALOAD statement that is, there is a variable usage, I want to call encode function call such that the variable is encoded during the usage..
So my plan is to add encode invoke stmt after the ALOAD statement.
How to achieve this?

Comment: What is the relationship between your first code snippet and the second code snippet and between either of them to what you described at the end?

Answer (score 0):

So you have to call encode method with string arg.
First of all you have to write method: `public static String encode(String arg) { /* Some code */ }`
Than you can call that method via asm

```
il.add(new FieldInsnNode(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;"));
// 1 - first variable in non-static function
// 0 - first variable in static funcnion. Choose wisely.
il.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ALOAD, 1);
// itf must be true if full.path.to.Class is interface
il.add(new MethodInsnNode(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "full/path/to/Class", "encode", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;", false); 
il.add(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "encode", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V"));
     methodNode.instructions.insertBefore(abstractNode, il);
```

Comment: Hey I have a doubt.
So suppose I have a calling function like
debug("abc",z) and want to convert to debug("abc",encrypt(z)), What should I do?

Comment: `il.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ALOAD, 1);` loads your local variable at index 1(first variable in non-static function).  

`il.add(new MethodInsnNode(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "full/path/to/Class", "encode", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;", false);` calls static function encode that should be in class full.path.to.Class
`il.add(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V"));
     methodNode.instructions.insertBefore(abstractNode, il);` calls println function
Where is the problem?